# Частица НЕ и причастие

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, причастия

Как правильно пишется слово незнающий в предложении?

*Создай отдельный сайт, включив туда всех незнающих чужие номера.*

Comment: Можете увидеть другие ответы на эту тему (НЕ и причастие), пользуясь опцией Искать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

А давайте у Розенталя спросим: [§ 60. Частица не с причастиями](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80)

"Пишется раздельно частица не с полными формами причастия, имеющими при себе **пояснительные слова**: не возвращённая автору рукопись; не замеченные корректором опечатки; не сданные в срок гранки; не изданные при жизни писателя варианты отдельных глав романа.

**Данное правило распространяется и на причастия, употребляемые в роли существительных**: В числе **не явившихся** на заседание были Петров и Сергеев.

Но с **субстантивированным причастием** (т. е. при перешедшем в разряд существительных) частица не пишется слитно: В классе много **неуспевающих по русскому языку".**

Тогда пишем НЕ раздельно:

**Создай отдельный сайт, включив туда всех не знающих чужие номера.**

Как объяснить? Неуспевающие по русскому языку - это общепринятый термин, в который входит субстантивированное причастие и зависимое слово. А не знающие (чужие номера) - это причастие, которое только в данном тексте употреблено в значении существительного.

Comment: Один маленький момент вызывает у меня сомнение. По-моему, дело не в том, что  "неуспевающие по русскому языку - это общепринятый термин", а в том, что субстантивированное причастие "неуспевающие" имеет смысл "отстающие", и в этом смысле в любом сочетании должно писаться слитно (напр. неуспевающие в первом семестре) , в отличие, например, от "не успевающие сделать уроки", где "не успевающие" имеет другой смысл.

Comment: Вообще-то тема смутная, для перехода в существительное  причастие должно развить значение предметности, получить возможность иметь определение, в предложении быть дополнением или подлежащим.. Здесь только определение подходит, да и то несогласованное. По-моему в данном случае  важен фактор устойчивости и замены синонимом без НЕ: неуспевающие (отстающие) по разным предметам. И вот что еще важно - это семантика нашего глагола, так как у него модальное значение и он используется в качестве вспомогательного. Потеряв основной глагол, он и переходит в существительное.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно:

> Создай отдельный сайт, включив туда всех незнающих чужие номера.

*Незнающих* здесь субстантивированное причастие (то есть перешедшее в разряд существительного); здесь нет отрицания, поэтому *не* пишется слитно.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, здесь причастие, имеющее при себе зависимые слова, и поэтому "не" пишется отдельно.

**Создай отдельный сайт, включив туда всех не знающих чужие номера.**

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

*Так всё ясно было им, пока не приехал этот авантюрист, **не знающий** России, лишённый всякого положительного равномерного опыта, и, захлёбываясь, дёргаясь и картавя, не полез со своими апрельскими тезисами, запутал всё окончательно! [Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 1-25 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990]*

Незнающий (слитное написание) означает "Такой, который не имеет достаточных знаний, опыта в какой-л. области; несведущий." (http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-ortho-term-50427.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Частица НЕ употребляется с причастием ЗНАЮЩИЕ. Причастие имеет зависимые слова - *чужие номера*. По правилам русского языка в этом случае частица НЕ с причастием, имеющим зависимые слова, пишется раздельно.